# Can I perform a 2 proportion z test on this data?

Tags: probability, statistics

I am comparing word frequencies in two corpora. I sort the words by difference of frequency across the two corpora. I take the 200 most favored words from corpus A and the 100 most favored words from corpus B. I then categorize the words as falling into 3 categories (sports, politics, cooking). Now, for corpus A I have 20 words in sports, 30 words in politics, and 50 in cooking. Corpus B has 5,55,40. I now want to check whether the difference in the proportion of words that fall into each category is significant.  I want to confirm that it's ok to do a 2 proportion ttest: eg, for sports, 20/100 for A v 5/100 for B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data you give are as follows:

```
 Cat      A      B
 -----------------
 Sp      20      5
 Pl      30     55
 Ck      50     40
```

In any case, you would not want to test Sports, Politics, and Cooking
in three separate tests as you suggest.

One correct test would be a chi-squared test for homogeniety.
It involves finding expected counts in each of the six cells
of your table and comparing them with observed counts.

Clearly, these are contrived data.
(It would be very rare for six real-world counts all to end
in 0 or 5.) You should be able to find computational details
for this kind of test in a basic statistics textbook.

Using software, I got a chi-squared statistic of about 17.5.
When compared with a chi-squared distribution with 2 degrees
of freedom, that gives an extremely small P-value, and thus
leads one to conclude that corpora A and B have different
probability distributions for categories sports, politics, and
cooking. I will leave it to you to see if you can do the
computations as shown in your text to get these answers.

Your suggested method with proportions and the normal distribution
would be OK if you had only two categories, say 'Politics' and
'Other'.

Comment: Thank you. From what I see for the chi-square test for homogeneity, it looks like the null hypothesis is that A and B are the same for each category (cooking, etc) and that the the alternative is that they are different for at least one. I would like to analyze them all however (eg, I want to see if the two corpora are significantly different for sports, then see if the two corpora are significantly different for politics, and so on). Is this possible with the chi-square?

Comment: Why not test them in three separate tests?

Comment: To reframe my question, suppose you have two corpora A and B each of 1000 words. You pull 100 words and notice that the two happen to mention sports 20 for A, 5 for B. I want to know: IF they do not actually differ in the amount of times they mention sports within the 1000 word entire body, what are the odds that you would pull 100 and get 20 for A and 5 for B by chance alone? If that chance is small, then they probably don't mention it the same, so it's significant.

Comment: However-- as you can see, I'm not really taking a random sample from the 1000 words, but instead taking the 100 words that are most favored by either corpus.

Comment: By the way, not a homework exercise; I used the numbers above to simplify (and inadvertently complicated by messing up the sports count, as noted)

Comment: The more I think about this, the less I think that I even need a statistical test at all. I think descriptive statistics is better for this purpose?

Comment: The first thing is to see if there are _any_ differences. If so, then you can look at the components of chi-squared, which will indicate where the differences are (components larger than 2). Then test that category individually. If you test all individually, there are difficulties: (1) three tests at 5% level can give much more than 5% error probability for the pattern of differences, (2) tests are not independent because column totals are fixed and so if 'sports' is high something else has to be low. If you can start new item with real data, some of these issues might be fruitfully discussed.

Comment: Descriptive statistics for this kind of cross-tabulated data can be very deceiving. The exact same proportions that are significant with 1000 words may not be significant with 200, yet bar charts could be indistinguishable. In general, descriptive statistical methods are still poorly developed for categorical data.

Comment: I realize that, but it seems that one would use statistics to generalize from a sample to the population (eg, since the sports proportion of A is 20/200 and B is 5/100, I would like to state that this is true for the rest of the text). However, I have the entire text. Whatsmore, my sample is not random--it's comprised of the 100 or 200 words that show the most discrepancy between corpora. If you have the population numbers, why use a statistical test on it?

Comment: If these two corpora are the only ones of their types you'll ever be interested in, I see your point. You started out asking about statistical tests on specific (if fake) data. Focus is getting blurrier not sharper with each comment. Mining text is is one thing. Having a defined purpose in mind for the results seems to be another, more difficult thing.